# How to make Floating Action Button oval in shape

Tags: android, floating-action-button

[image]

I want to make floating action button like in figure.What i have tried uptil now is that i have tried both way i.e. created shape in drawable and also tried with image with .png extension.Tried using both android:drawable and android:src but what happend is that it gets embedded inside FAB . It doesnt replaced previous one.How can i make FAB of type shown in figure .

Comment: What happend if you just put a long string inside the fab?

Comment: written inside oval shape which is in FAB